# ExtJS Scatter Plot, Highlight Certain Points According to Flag in Data

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts, extjs4, series

I want to figure out a way to highlight certain points in my scatter plot. I've spent some time looking into it but have found no easy way. If I was plotting data that looked like this:

- numberOne: 50, numberTwo:45, highlight:0
- numberOne: 65, numberTwo:30, highlight:0
- numberOne: 35, numberTwo:50, highlight:1
- numberOne: 25, numberTwo:45, highlight:1
- numberOne: 60, numberTwo:75, highlight:0

So the points representing the third and fourth row above would show up as a different shape or color or size. Does anyone have any insight on this?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured out how to do it using a renderer in the series, here is my code:

```
            renderer:function(sprite, record, attr, index){
                    console.log(record.get('highlight'));
                    console.log(sprite);
                    var highlight = record.get('highlight');
                    var color = null;
                    if (highlight == 1) {
                            color = "#1BE01B";
                    }else{
                            color = "#E81717";
                    }
                            return Ext.apply(attr, { fill: color });
            }
```